# convert normal diff to unified diff or use normal diff in patch

Tags: compiling, convert, patch, diff

I have a normal diff file but I can't patch with it.

So how can I convert this normal diff to unified diff or patch with normal diff file?

```
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: misc.o
diff -r ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common/mobilenode.cc
64a65,68
> #ifdef        GgX
> #include "wireless-phy.h"
> #include "mac-802_11.h"
> #endif        GgX
128a133
> 
147a153,157
> 
> #ifdef  GgX
>       Mac802_11* macptr;
> #endif  GgX
> 
266a277,294
> 
> #ifdef GgX //GgX - To have an access to change rate!
>               } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "change_rate") == 0) {
>                       macptr = (Mac802_11*) ifhead_.lh_first->uptarget();
>                       if (macptr) {
>                               // Keep attention GgX supposes only 1
>                               // interface present!
>                               macptr->setRate(atoi(argv[2])); 
>                               fprintf(stderr, "Rate changed to: %d\n\n",\
>                                               atoi(argv[2]));
>                               return TCL_OK;
>                       } else {
>                               fprintf(stderr, "Error.. Mac not found..\n");
>                               return(TCL_ERROR);
>                       };
>                       return TCL_OK;
> #endif // GgX
> 
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: mobilenode.o
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: net-interface.o
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: node.o
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: ns-process.o
Only in /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common: object.o
diff -r ns-2.26/common/packet.h /tmp/ns-allinone-2.26/ns-2.26/common/packet.h
128c128,129
< 
---
>       PT_MON_NDP,
>       PT_ZRP,
211a213,215
>               name_[PT_MON_NDP]="Mon_Ndp";
> 
>               name_[PT_ZRP]="ZRP"; 
322a327
>         double mon_info_;
375d379
< 
430c434
< 
---
>       double my_power_;
```